# two groups in Autocompletetext Android

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview

I have an AutocompleteTextView element in my Android app. It works ok, but I want to improve it.

This Autocomplete element shows a list of elements that I ask to server using the constraint and a fixed query (position).

My question is how can I do to add groups in the "ListView" that shows all the solutions, like grouped by a title?

An image shows better what i ask:

[image]

Comment: You gonna display data grouped in listview or in autocompletetextview?

Comment: it is all done in your custom `Adapter` you are using in your `ACTV`

Comment: @mwisnicki in a autocompletetextview, in their droplist

What do you mean @pskink?? I have my Adapter, but I don't know how create the title of each list

Comment: see `Adapter#getItemViewType(int position)` and `Adapter#getViewTypeCount()`